# How do you sort an array in the most efficient way when given the largest value?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Let's say that i have an array of size n and the largest value of this array is k.

Let's assume that `k=log(sqrt(n))` and I want to sort this array in the most efficient way possible ,to do this I've simplified the equation to get `k` in terms of `n` and I've got `n=2^2k` that's my array size.

Now if i apply any sorting algorithm of `Θ(n^(2))` the time complexity will be equal to `Θ(2^(4k))` in terms of `n` this will be `Θ(n^2)`
,and if i apply a `Θ(nlogn)` sorting algorithm i will have `Θ(k*2^(2k))` and in terms of n i will have `Θ(nlog(sqrt(n)))` which is the most efficient time complexity ,did i do this right?

And if i assume `k=n^n` can I use the same method as i used before?
for this I'm failing to denote the array size in terms of k to use the same method ,is there another way ?

Comment: Knowing the largest element in the array does not help at all with sorting. And `Θ(nlog(sqrt(n)))` is the same as `Θ(nlog(n))` (the sqrt inside log just contributes a constant factor)

Comment: if you only want to compare nlogn and n^2, I guess 'k' is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the largest element value k in an array you want to sort, might help, especially if, as in your case k < n. In this case you can use [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) an will have a runtime of O(n + k)

Comment: This is only true if you know the lowest value as well and if the values are integer.

Comment: I completely agree.